# How to display a non-modal CDialog?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++, cdialog

Can someone tell me how I could create a Non Modal Dialog in MFC's Visual c++ 6.0 and show it? 
I wrote this code:

```
CDialog dialog;
if (dialog.init(initialization values...))
   dialog.DoModal();
```

But it blocks my application from showing the dialog. I dont know if there exists any method or other way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

```
/* CChildDialog class is inherited from CDialog */
CChildDialog *m_pDialog = NULL;

// Invoking the Dialog
m_pDialog = new CChildDialog();

if (m_pDialog != NULL)
{
      BOOL ret = m_pDialog->Create(IDD_CHILDDIALOG, this);

      if (!ret)   //Create failed.
      {
         AfxMessageBox(_T("Error creating Dialog"));
      }    
      m_pDialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}

// Delete the dialog once done
delete m_pDialog;
```

Comment: delete m_pDialog; it could crash the application.

you can call m_pDialog->DestroyWindow (); to delete dialog.

Comment: Will the dialog be delete itself if I close it?

Comment: According to MSFT, dialogs are not designed for auto-cleanup. But as long as you aren't doing anything fancy with memory or handle allocations, it will normally work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn017-destroying-window-objects?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 5):

Use CDialog::Create and then use CDialog::ShowWindow.  You now have a modeless dialog box.

Answer (score 5):

You can call [`CDialog::Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhth57kd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`CWnd::ShowWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/72szh9c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like the others have suggested.

Also, keep in mind your dialog will be **destroyed right after its creation** if it is stored in a local variable.

Answer (score 5):

In this case I find it most convenient to let it self-delete itself to handle the cleanup.

Often it's considered bad form to make "implicit" memory freeing from within a class, and not by what it created it, but I usually make exceptions for modeless dialog boxes.

That is;

Calling code:

```
#include "MyDialog.h"

void CMyApp::OpenDialog()
{
    CMyDialog* pDlg = new CMyDialog(this);
    if (pDlg->Create(IDD_MYDIALOG, this))
        pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    else
        delete pDlg;
}
```

Dialog code:

```
void CMapBasicDlg::OnDestroy()
{
    CDialog::OnDestroy();
    delete this; // Shown as non-modal, we'll clean up ourselves
}
```

Comment: This is closer to correct than the current top answer, but the delete should actually be done in OnNcDestroy.  WM_DESTROY marks the start of the destruction sequence, WM_NCDESTROY marks the end.  You want to wait until the latter (last message it will receive) to delete the MFC dialog.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `CDialog::Create` instead.  You will need to call `DestroyWindow` when you are finished with the dialog.  You might also need to pass dialog messages onto the object but I can't remember if MFC handles this for you or not.

Answer (score 3):

DoModal is blocking. You have to create your dialog on the heap or make it a member of your class (this is important), call Create then call ShowWindow.